# php time string array - delete values for specific period

Tags: php, arrays

```
[0] => 12:00:00
[1] => 12:15:00
[2] => 12:30:00
[3] => 12:45:00
[5] => 13:15:00
[6] => 13:30:00
[7] => 13:45:00
[8] => 14:00:00
[9] => 14:15:00
[10] => 14:30:00
```

How to delete the values from above array when my starttime is "**12:30:00**" and endtime is "**14:00:00**" ? The values should be deleted are **12:30:00, 12:45:00, 13:15:00, 13:45:00 and 14:00:00**

Comment: Which values? Define your requirements explicitly please. `startTime < t < endTime` or `startTime <= t < endTime` or `startTime < t <= endTime` or `startTime <= t <= endTime` or something completely different...? And what have you tried so far? We don't just "do it for you" here

Comment: use array_splice php function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php)

Comment: Are your timestamps stored in array as strings?

Comment: yeah, they are stored as strings

Comment: Which PHP version do you have, exactly? Is it greater than 5.2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For PHP >= 5.2.0, I would do something like this:

```
$time_array = array('0' => '11:00:00',
                    '1' => '12:00:00',
                    '2' => '13:00:00',
                    '3' => '14:00:00',
                    '4' => '15:00:00',
                    '5' => '16:00:00');

echo "\nBefore:\n";
print_r($time_array);

$start = new DateTime('12:30:00');
$end   = new DateTime('14:00:00');

// Magic starts here
foreach ($time_array as $key => $value) {
  $datetime = new DateTime($value);
  if ($datetime >= $start and $datetime <= $end)
    unset($time_array[$key]);
}
// Magic finished

echo "\nAfter:\n";
print_r($time_array);
```

[Yes, it works.](http://codepad.org/0JvkRI3e)

Comment: Fixed. Had no possibility to test it for the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this if you dont need to preserve indexes

```
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  $array = array(
    0 => '12:00:00',
    1 => '12:15:00',
    2 => '12:30:00',
    3 => '12:45:00',
    5 => '13:15:00',
    6 => '13:30:00',
    7 => '13:45:00',
    8 => '14:00:00',
    9 => '14:15:00',
    10 => '14:30:00',
  );

  $from = '12:30:00';
  $to   = '14:00:00';
  $filtered = array();
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
  if ($value < $from || $value > $to) {
          $filtered[] = $value;
 }
  }

  var_dump($filtered);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. do we really need sort function there?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $var_arr = array();
    $time_arr = array('12:00:00','12:15:00','12:30:00','12:45:00','13:15:00',
'13:30:00','13:45:00','14:00:00','14:15:00','14:30:00'); 
    $start = strtotime('12:30:00');
    $end = strtotime('14:00:00');
    foreach($time_arr as $arr):
    if(strtotime($arr)<$start || strtotime($arr)>$end):
    $var_arr[] = $arr;
    endif;
    endforeach;
    print_r($var_arr);
```

Comment: strtotime() for getting pure numeric value to make the comparison batter.